# JavaScript NodeJs Open Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, npm

I am trying to open multiple images simultaneously in the default Windows Photo Viewer that I have stored in my folder using the npm open library:

```
let files = ['Dog.gif', 'Cat.jpeg'];
for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
  open(`${files[i]}`, {wait:true});
}
```

But it's only opening the first file? I am not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Never done anything similar, but could the `wait: true` parameter cause the problem?

Comment: No, I tried removing it, and no luck

Comment: set it to false

Comment: No, that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it happened because the file name or file type did not exist or did not match the source file

Answer (score 0):

`{wait: true}` is supposed to cause `open()` to wait until you exit the application that opens the file before resuming execution. So if you expect them all to open at the same time, remove the `{wait: true}` option.

If you, in fact, do want it to wait until the application exits before opening the second file and hare having it only open one file, read on for at least some minimal debugging help.

Assuming you are using a recent version of `open`, it is a promise-based API. It seems to make it hard to get at errors. However, you can at least confirm that you're getting an error like this:

```
const open = require('open');

let files = ['dog.txt', 'cat.txt'];
(async () => {
  for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    const cp = await open(`${files[i]}`, {wait: true});
    console.log(`${files[i]} exit code: ${cp.exitCode}`);
  }
})();
```

That will print an error code of `0` for all files where `open()` succeeded and a non-zero value for all files where `open()` failed.

Comment: After removing {wait: true} option and running this code, I get exit code: null for both of my images but the first image still opens?

Comment: You can't remove `wait` in the second suggestion and expect to get an `exitCode` because `open()` won't wait for the process to exit before returning. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: Ok so I just wanted the 2 image files to open at the same time and I used the async and await with {wait: true} and it seems to be working.